# Английский vs Russian - как правильно?

Tags: иноязычная-лексика

Здравствуйте гуманитарии.
Возник вопрос, реализовал систему, а как правильно назвать не сильно знаю.
Сам вопрос - как правильно в русском языке будет написать:
1. онлайн консультация или online консультация?
2. оффлайн версия или offline версия?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласно Орфографическому словарю правильно:

онлайн-консультация, офлайн-версия.

Comment: И произошедшее от англ. **off** приставка **оф** теряет одну ф?

Comment: Да, теряет

Answer (score 2):

Дополнение по поводу одной буквы Ф

Офлайн - англ. offline, отключённый от сети. 
Заимствованные слова не всегда сохраняют графику оригинала, что мы видим на примере слова "офлайн". Именно в такой форме оно занесено в орфографические словари, хотя до сих пор в сети встречаются вариант "оффлайн".

Отсутствие двойной согласной можно объяснить тем, что в русском языке отсутствует удвоение, аналогичное английскому, и поэтому имеет смысл передать написание предлога of с одной буквой Ф.

Для сравнения: одна буква Ф пишется также в заимствованном слове офис - от англ. office.

Comment: @София, Спасибо Вам за развёрнутый ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Слова "онлайн" и "оффлайн" уже давно вошли в русский язык, поэтому нет нужды записывать их латиницей. Но тут встает другой вопрос: как правильно писать эти слова? Есть вариант слитно "онлайн" и через дефис "он-лайн". Насколько я знаю, применимы оба этих варианта.

Comment: Словарь Лопатина "Слитно, раздельно иди через дефис?" даёт только слитный вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Помощь tat неграмотная. 
Zuzik knows Russian uncertainly and certainly doesn't know English.
Формула Дайхеса
Лёля неуверенно знает русский и уверенно не знает английский.

on line - на линии. Сегодня в контексте Интернета on line стал бытовым синонимом Сети. Правописание ещё не установилось: on line, on-line, online, и в словарях есть эти три варианта.
off line - вне, без использования сети услуг. Off grid - жить, где нет электр., канализ., водопровода и пр. Таким мест достаточно, много в Монтане, на Аляске.

---

Я учу студентов: не используйте слов, семантику которых не знаете.

Ответ на вопрос.  
1. an on line consultation - консультация, совет, урок в Интернете (учебнике, школе, на курсах, при встрече...). 
2. an off-line version -- большей частью с коммерческим смыслом: версия программы, книга, товар... не продаётся в Интернете, нужно заказать по почте или прийти в магазин, может значить (не часто): есть в Инт., но не бесплатно. По-русски: (сам) товар (версия и пр.) не в Интернете.

off camera - вне поля камеры. 
a statement off the record - неподтверждённое заявление.

Не надо пресмыкаться перед чужой страной. Не уважаешь Его Величество Язык Русский - не выходи на люди, не позорь его.

Developer - одно из значений - застройщик. В США он покупает землю и строит на ней дома, которые продаёт или отдаёт в аренду. Не путать со строителем - builder, constructor. 
Я вижу в ваших СМИ: мой муж девелопер, вот он девелопернёт билдингу, и мы драйвим в саут. 
Откуда ВДРУГ у вас столь холуского пресмыкания перед грязным и подловатым амер. населением!